# Scala Parser Combinators Matching Wrong Parser

Tags: scala, parsing, language-design, parser-combinators

I am writing an *extremely* simple programming language using scala's parsers. I am trying to allow users to have multi-word variables ie `my variable` and I want to allow them to assign variables in three ways: `let var = 2`, `var =2`, `set var to 4`. I have the first two working, but I cant get the latter to work.

Here is my code

```
      lazy val line:PackratParser[Line] = (assignment | element | comment) <~ (";" | "[\n\r]*".r)

      lazy val assignment:PackratParser[Assignment] = assignmentLHS ~ element ^^ {
        case x ~ y => new Assignment(x,y)
      }

      lazy val assignmentLHS =  "set" ~ "[" ~> identifier <~ "]" ~ "to" | ("let"?) ~> identifier <~ "="

      lazy val identifier:Parser[String] = "([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]* ?)+".r ^^ (X => if (X.charAt(X.length-1) == ' ') X.substring(0, X.length-1) else X)

     lazy val element:PackratParser[Element] =(
        functionDef
      | comparison
      | expression
      | boolean
      | controlStatement
      | functionCall
      | reference
      | value
      | codeBlock

    )
    lazy val reference: PackratParser[Reference] = identifier ^^ (x=>new Reference(x))
```

Elements are most things in the language.

I would like to replace the assignmentLHS parser with:

```
  lazy val assignmentLHS =  "set" ~> identifier <~ "to" | ("let"?) ~> identifier <~ "="
```

so that the user can write `set my variable to 4` instead of `set [my variable] to 4. The problem is that it just parses that as a reference

Comment: Why do you have ~ `"[" "]"` surrounding the identifier?  You do not include that in your "desired' syntax

Comment: @javadba I do at the bottom, I want to use the on without the square brackets but the one in the main block is the only thing I could get to work

Comment: Why do you have a space in the identifier before the 'optional' ? symbol: `.. 0-9]* ?)+`  ? Maybe the "set " is becoming melded with the identifier for that reason.  I added an answer to show better

Comment: @javadba no, it is not homework. I am trying to build a simple programming language that supports multiple word variables ie `my variable` so that the assignment would look like this: `set my variable to 40`

Comment: OK I have deleted that comment. Give me a few mins I will try to figure out how to allow spaces.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a space in the identifier before the 'optional' '?' symbol:

```
0-9]* ?)+
```

Maybe that is causing

```
set <identifier>
```

to  change to

set other_chars

and `set` becomes *part* of the identifier.  That would explain why your use of

```
"set" ~ "[" ~> identifier <~ "]"
```

works but

```
"set" ~> identifier <~ "to"
```

does not

Comment: The space is there to allow for multiple word variable names like my variable

Comment: The point is: that space is likely also making it so that "set " is not working. Why don't you take out the space - and see if you were able to get the grammar working for cases *not* including the multiple word variable names.